# Can't find "Convert to MotionLayout" in android studio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have tried adding different implementations for constraintlayout

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
```

Cleaning the project, still right clicking on constraintLayout does not show "Convert to motionLayout". I need to manually add another xml file under the xml directory for the motion. Looked into other people's problems. Seems they had the dependency issue. Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: make sure you have updated your Android studio to the latest version

Comment: Pls post it as an answer so that I can accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MotionLayout editor is available in Android Studio [starting from version 4.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#4-0-0-design-tools). Make sure that you have updated your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

use

"implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'

Make sure your project compiles at that point.
Then convert.

This small (< 2min) video shows the conversion:
https://twitter.com/i/status/1187075643118239744